# Python3: install github-based module in setup.py?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, setuptools

Installing with `pip`, I can write the following `requirements.txt` file:

```
git+https://repo@branch#egg=foo&subdirectory=this/bar/foo
numpy
```

And successfully install the requirements file:

```
python3 -m pip install -r requirements.tx
```

However, I have co-located in the directory a `setup.py` script that lists:

```
setuptools.setup(
  ...
  install_requires = get_lines('requirements.txt'),
  ...
)
```

And installing this submodule using `pip` involves `pip` running `setup.py`...which fails to handle the module link:

```
git+https://github.com/repo@branch#egg=foo&subdirectory=this/bar/foo
```

---

I can see *a lot* of ways around this, but it seems like there should be one non-ambiguous way to do this which changes as little as possible in the `setup.py` script.

Is there such a way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to change the line in `requirements.txt` to something like:

```
foo @ git+https://repo@branch#egg=foo&subdirectory=this/bar/foo
```

References:

- https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#requirement-specifiers
- https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0440/#direct-references

Although I am not entirely sure it will work. There might be subtle differences between the notations accepted in `requirements.txt` files, *pip* directly and *setuptools*. In particular I do not know how well things like `egg` and `subdirectory` are supported.

Advices:

- Avoid calling `python setup.py install` or `python setup.py develop` from now on, and make sure to call `python -m pip install .` or `python -m pip install --editable .` instead.
- I do consider reading `requirements.txt` from within `setup.py` as a red flag (or at least yellow). The contents of `install_requires` of *setuptools* and `requirements.txt` usually serve different purposes.

Comment: So I probably need to add information:  I am installing with `python3 -m pip install foo`.  And I do like the editable flag, but I am not using it here.  Also, setup and requirements may be for different purposes at some point.  But I have stripped down the requirements file so that it consists of exactly what is needed for a valid install.   Also, if I could drop the setup pattern entirely, I would do it -- no vested, habitual or idiomatic interest in that on my end.

Comment: In other words, in this particular use case, the `setup.py` is more of a ritual than a feature.  Pip needs to come in, install the requirements, and install all the python files in the directory.

Comment: @Chris So have you tried the `foo @ ...` notation or not? -- If I recommend calling `pip` instead of `setup.py`, it is because _setuptools_ doesn't understand this `foo @` notation, or at least it didn't last time I checked. Which is fine, _setuptools_ does not really need to understand that notation, it just writes verbatim the line in the distribution metadata. -- For the `install_requires` vs. `requirements.txt`, fair enough, just a warning that it might be a symptom for some deeper misunderstanding, but you seem to know what you're doing on this front, so all good.

Comment: If you want to get rid of `setup.py`, I would recommend looking into replacing it with the combination `setup.cfg` + `pyproject.toml`.

Comment: It is for work, so I won't try it until Monday.  That sounds like a good alternative.  And, I may actually leverage requirements.txt for editable installs from git or cloned paths... so the setup.py pattern may be worth it.  I'll try these things out then.  At the moment, hammering my head against Vulkan + Nvidia RTX on Linux ha.

Comment: all worked! and got setup.py figured out too.