# What if setup.py is not at the root of a dependency link?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, setup.py

I recently came across a Python package that had `setup.py` located not inside the package root.

```
package
|
|--cpp
|  |
|  |--<cpp stuff>
|
|--python
|  |
|  |--setup.py
|  |--<python stuff>
```

I cannot simply point `dependency_links` in `setup.py` to the python folder, because the repo can only be downloaded as a whole (it comes in a tarball).

How would one handle a dependency like this?  Possibly a download and then a local reference in `setup` like

```py
install_requires=['package @ file://localhost/{}'.format(
    os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), '..', 'package', 'python'))]
```

Comment: Would it not be easier to just build a (likely binary, if C++ is involved) wheel out of the package and require it?

Comment: As AKX said: I would recommend you to avoid referencing this tarball directly, instead build a wheel out of this library and reference the wheel as a dependency of your project. -- Otherwise, maybe look at this, in case it helps (I doubt it): https://stackoverflow.com/a/65858081

Comment: @AKX the funny part is that the Python code does not include C++ bindings.  They are both just clients.  Otherwise I'd do as you said.

Comment: @studentbrad So even better, you can just build a non-binary wheel out of the python bits with `python setup.py bdist_wheel`!

Comment: @AKX Consider making that an answer if you want it accepted.  Worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To em-answer my comment:

You could just build a wheel (.whl) of the Python bits with

```
python setup.py bdist_wheel
```

and use the generated wheel as your dependency.